# Why does this code returns last line of T matrix

Tags: python, list

```
class Solution:
    """
    rotates, queries and stuff blah blah blah
    """
    def mains(self):
     pass


    def rotate(self,A):
     n = len(A[0])
     T = [[0]*n]*n 
     # the above part is erraneous probably, on individual initialization it works!
     for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(n):
             T[i][j] = A[j][i]


     print T



p = Solution()
p.rotate([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

the output is [[3,6,9],[3,6,9],[3,6,9]] which is not the transpose

Comment: I guess it is worthwhile to mention again the neat (python-3) `T = list(zip(*p))`

Comment: @Aguy it works in Python 2 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `[[0]*n]*n` creates a list of size `n` filled with *references to the same list* (`[0]*n`), so when you're accessing `T[i][j]`, you're using the same memory location.

Here are some examples of different setup:

```
>>> T=[[0]*5]*5
>>> T
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> T[0][0]=5
>>> T #goes nuts
[[5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

>>> T=[[0 for _ in range(5)]]*5
>>> T
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> T[0][0]=5
>>> T #goes wrong
[[5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

>>> T=[[0 for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]
>>> T
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> T[0][0]=5
>>> T #this is correct!
[[5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

>>> T=[[0]*5 for _ in range(5)]
>>> T
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> T[0][0]=5
>>> T #this is also correct!
[[5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

In the examples except the first one, I'm using [list comprehensions](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/), which are a very powerful way to create lists and fill them with data at the same time.

Comment: This really helped @ForceBru!

Comment: @Vashisht.gupta then you should accept this answer.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Yeah, i did :)

Comment: @Vashisht.gupta you disn't. You have merely up-voted it. There is a check-mark under the vote score.

Answer (score 2):

With your approach, the same *sublist* is duplicated `n` times:

```
T = [[0]*n]*n
```

So changes are reflected across them simultaneously.

---

You should instead set up `T` like so:

```
T = [[0]*n for _ in range(n)]
```

This would create `n` independent sublists.

Answer (score 2):

You got caught by the mutability of `list` instances. Here

```
T = [[0]*n]*n
```

The inner multiplication creates `n` references to an `int` instance. Since Python's `int`s are immutable, when you change one, a new object and a new reference is created in the background. `list`s are different. Your outer multiplication copies the reference to the same list, namely `[0] * n`. Since Python's lists are mutable, whenever you change it through one reference, the change is reflected across all references, because  they all reference the same object in memory.

For example:

```
a = b = 3
b = 4
print(a, b)  # 3 4
```

And notice, what happens with a mutable object:

```
a = b = [1, 2, 3]
b[1] = 0
print(a, b)  # [1, 0, 3] [1, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also build your list while looping:

```
>>> T = []
>>> 
>>> for i in xrange(3):
        T.append([])
             for j in xrange(3):
                 T[i].append(l[j][i])


>>> T
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```